# Why can't I refer to the variable $USER in an "else" block of shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, quotes

I have two "sayHello" shell scripts with only slightly changes on "if-else" test.

Here are the codes:

- sayHello1

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -e -p "What is your name? "

if [ -n $REPLY ]; then
    echo "Hello ${REPLY}!"
else
    echo "Hello ${USER}!"
fi
```

- output for sayHello1 (I just pressed ENTER)

```
$ What is your name? 
$ Hello !
```

Here comes the strange thing. **Why is $USER not shown in output?**

If I change the test order as shown bellow:

- sayHello2

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -e -p "What is your name? "

if [ -z $REPLY ]; then
    echo "Hello ${USER}!"
else
    echo "Hello ${REPLY}!"
fi
```

- output for sayHello2 (again, pressed ENTER)

```
$ What is your name? 
$ Hello rit!
```

it worked as expected.

With further test, I found that the command `echo "${USER}` can work expectedly anywhere outside "else-fi" block (within the script).

Why does this happen? How to explain it?

Comment: Quotes are not optional in shell. Make it `[ -n "$REPLY" ]`

Comment: Otherwise, it becomes `[ -n ]` when REPLY is empty, which is equivalent to `[ -n -n ]`, because `-n` is the default operator to `test` when it has only one argument.

Comment: If you run your code though http://shellcheck.net/, follow the links in the warnings it generates.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right. It seems that an unquoted empty string is the problem. After I added the quotation marks, everything worked fine. Thank you.